# Android transition shared element between three fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to implement some nice transitions between fragments using shared elements and here's what i want to achieve:

[image]

When i switch from **fragment 1** to **fragment 2**:

- **fragment 1** fades out
- **logo** moves to top left
- **fragment 2** comes from bottom.

When i switch from **fragment 2** to **fragment 3**:

- **fragment 2** fades out
- **logo** "doesn't move"
- **Title 1** moves left
- **Title 2** comes from right
- **fragment 3** comes from bottom

Here's the settings for **fragment 1**:

**Fagment1.java:**

```
fragment.setExitTransition("fade"); //parameter shortened for readability
```

**XML:**

```
<ImageView [...]
    android:id="@+id/octopuss"
    android:transitionName="@string/octopuss"/>
```

Here's the settings for **fragment 2**:

**Fragment2.java:**

```
fragment3.setEnterTransition("slide_bottom");
fragment3.setSharedElementEnterTransition("move");
fragment3.setExitTransition("fade");
```

**XML:**

```
<ImageView [...]
    android:transitionName="@string/octopuss"/>

<TextView [...]
    android:transitionName="title1"
    android:id="@+id/title1" />
```

**Call for fragment 2 in Activity:**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fullscreen_content, fragment2)
    .addToBackStack("connection_transaction");
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)     
    ft.addSharedElement(findViewById(R.id.octopuss), getString(R.string.octopuss));
ft.commit();
```

Here's the settings for **fragment 3**:

**Fragment3.java:**

```
fragment3.setEnterTransition("slide_bottom");
fragment3.setSharedElementEnterTransition("slide_right");
```

**XML:**

```
<ImageView [...]
    android:transitionName="@string/octopuss"/>

<TextView [...]
    android:transitionName="title1"/>
```

**Call for fragmen 3 in Activity:**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fullscreen_content, fragment3)
    .addToBackStack("preferences_transaction");
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    ft.addSharedElement(findViewById(R.id.title1), "title1");
ft.commit();
```

Every transitions works very well between **fragment 1** and **fragment 2**.

But when i call for **fragment 3** each fragment starts its enterTransition\exitTansition like they had no shared element at all:

- Title 1 fades out with **fragment 2**
- Title 2 comes from bottom with **fragment 3**

Can someone help me to find why ? What i am missing ?

Comment: Can you clarify what shared elements fragments 2 and 3 are supposed to have? It seems that fragment 2 contains "Title 1" and fragment 3 contains "Title 2" but they're two separate elements in the transition you're describing. Do you have extra TextViews hidden offscreen in fragment 2 or 3 so that there are elements to share?

Comment: Good point ! In fact, "Title1" on fragment 2 and "Title2" on fragment 3 should be the shared element with trasitionName="title1" between those fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned into a bit of a lengthy answer: an explanation of why it isn't working and how to make it work.

**The problem**

I think there's some confusion here about what constitutes a Shared Element and how they work.

Remember the basic idea is that you are moving from one screen(activity or fragment) to another and that a Shared Element represents something that is present on both. For continuity and a smoother transition, you want that item to smoothly change from it's position on the first screen to the position on the second screen.

A Shared Element is *not* just an item that moves independently from the rest of the layout during a transition.

So with all that said; in this example the first transition where the large central logo changes to a small logo in the corner is a great example of a Shared Element transition.

The second isn't really a shared element transition.
I'm not sure what the line `fragment3.setSharedElementEnterTransition("slide_right");` contains (I think you abbreviated it for clarity) but I suspect it's being ignored when your app is running as it's not a valid shared element transition.

It doesn't make sense to tell a shared element to "slide right" as by definition the direction the element will move depends on where its counterpart is; it will move *there*, whichever direction that happens to be.

An actual shared element transition between Title 1 and Title 2 wouldn't look like much at all, since they're the same size in the same place, they'd just stay there.

**All is not lost**

The way you can make this work using Shared Element transition is to put Title 1 and Title 2 in *both* fragments and add *two* shared elements. In one fragment, Title 1 will be in the normal position and Title 2 will be hidden off the right-hand side of the screen. In the other Title 2 will be in normal position and Title 1 will be hidden off the left of screen.

For your off-screen TextViews use `android:translationX="-86dp"`(or some other number to position it off the left or right of the screen).

**Things to note:** you won't see the effect of the translationX attribute in your layout preview, only when you run the app.

Make sure you match up appropriate transitionNames for title1 and title2.

Comment: THANKS for this ! You're right, i kind of badly remixed shared element principles. Of course the code was reduced for clarity, th real definition looks like : `fragment.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));`. Moreover, it seams that only _move_ actually work with shared element.. I'll try what you suggest here and give you accepted answer for that helpful (not so lengthy) explanation.

Comment: I confirm it's working but it raised a question: how can i get the 'visible' width of 'Title1' in order to move 'Title 2' off screen whatever the scrensize is ? I tried : `title2.setTranslationX(title2.getMeasuredWidth());` inside `onCreateView()` with no result..